# What is a word for over-celebrating?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word similar to pompous or haughty. I thought of it for a while, and could not find a word that fit that description. It's also similar to tooting your own horn too much.

Comment: Hi, William. Welcome to English Language and Usage. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question with more context + an example sentence.

Comment: You could use "touchdown dance".

Comment: What about "gloating"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider *[showboating](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/showboating?a=british)*

> a ​slightly ​annoying ​form of ​behaviour, ​especially in ​sport, that is ​intended to ​attract ​attention or ​admiration because it is very ​skilful:
>
> *When he ​scored his fourth ​goal of the ​afternoon, we were ​forced to ​forgive his showboating and other ​antics.*

*Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

Also *[parading](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=parading&submit.x=25&submit.y=18)*. One of the definitions in *American Heritage* of *parade* is

> To exhibit ostentatiously; flaunt: *paraded their wealth.*

Answer (score 1):

For the sense of *vainglorious boasting*, with an upscale twist toward haughtiness, I like the verb

***bloviate***

which dictionary.reference.com describes as an American coinage marrying **blow** (as in **blowhard**) and a Latin-like inflection.  The source states that the word was favored by US President Warren G. Harding, for what it's worth.

Higher still on the scale is ***rodomontade***, a word I keep on a special shelf for dispkay, and hardly ever take down and use.  It's a noun, of course, and means **bloviating,** only a tarnation louder.  Our friends at dictionary.reference.com offer this interesting history to this 17th century blast:

> 1605-15; < Middle French < Italian Rodomonte, the boastful king of Algiers in Orlando Innamorato and Orlando Furioso + Middle French -ade

Got to love it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider "grandstanding".

› ​acting or ​speaking in a way ​intended to ​attract ​attention and to ​influence the ​opinion of ​people who are ​watching:

> Experts ​criticized the ​program as ​mere grandstanding by
>   ​corporations and ​local ​officials.

Comment: Please include the link for your definition.

Answer (score 0):

- [Boasting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boasting): a statement in which you express too much pride in yourself or in something you have, have done, or are connected to in some way (Merriam-Webster)

  > *"We were offended by his boast that he would easily beat us."*
- [Crow over](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boasting): To exult over a victory or accomplishment; to boast or vaunt. The allusion is to a gamecock’s exultant crowing after defeating an opponent. This expression dates from 1588. (The Free Dicitonary)

  > *"Alive, the question would be whether, being the victor, he would not crow over me."*
  >   A Little Girl in Old Philadelphia

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for an adjective. Would vainglorious do?

> Vainglorious people are vain, excessively boastful, and have swelled pride. The base word, vainglory, dates all the way back to the 14th century and means “worthless glory.”

From www.vocabulary.com

Answer (score 0):

You may say that **he is beating his own drums**, what means *to brag or boast about your accomplishments or achievements*.

"blow one's own trumpet" (BE) or "toot one's horn" (AE) are similar.

[image]